# Autodesk Forge API: "this project doesn't exist." Error

Tags: api, postman, autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-bim360

I am using Postman to make a POST call to add a user to an Autodesk BIM 360 Project.    https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/projects/:project_id/users
When I hit send I am getting the following error:

"code": 1004,
"message": "this project doesn't exist."

I know that my authorization works because I have used it for other calls. I got the project id from the URL so it should be correct. What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the suggested new workflow from that endpoint documentation 1st line.

Add a project admin to a specific BIM 360 project and service type. We recommend using [POST projects/:project_id/users/import (v2)](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST) for adding project admins and project users.

Comment: I tried the v2 as you suggested and am now getting the following error: "code": 1001,
    "message": "users list about to be imported are empty or in wrong format."
}